# Store object type in object

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a parent class A and some child classes B1,...Bn.
I would like at a point of time, having an object Bx of type A, to be able to say: this is a class Bx.

My first guess is to add a enum property inside class A defining each child class type and then store this child class type when constructing the child object:

```cs
public enum typeOfChild { B1, B..., Bn };  

public class A {     
    public typeOfChild type;
}

public class B1 : A {
    public B1() 
    {
        type = typeOfChild.B1;
    }
}

// So I can retrieve it later:
B1 Foo = new B1();

// What will happen is that I don't know the type of the child:
A FooA = Foo;

// And now I would like to retrieve this type:
Console.WriteLine(FooA.type); // B1
```

I need this type be sent back as a JSON property.

Is there a better/proper way to retrieve the child type of this object?

Comment: `GetType()` already returns the *runtime type* of an object, as opposed to the static type of the variable you're using to reference the object. It looks like you're trying to reinvent it.

Comment: `GetType()` what was I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these class definitions:

```
public class A {     
}

public class B : A {
}
```

You can find out the type of the *variable* (compile time detectable) and the type of the *instance* (runtime only):

```
A a = null;

if(/*user input*/)
{   
   a = new A();
}
else
{
   b = new B();
}

// this results in A, because that's the variable type
typeof(a); 

// this results in either A or B depending on how he "if" went,
// because that's the actual type of the instance
a.GetType();
```